# hover and mouseover effect repeat numerous times

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover, mouseleave

Have been working on a simple project, mostly completed the problem is that everything works fine except for the fact that hover and mouseleave events. Not sure how to fix it. 
Here is [the link](http://codepen.io/Griffinth/pen/MyopQV)

or

**HTML code**

```
<div id="container">
        <div class="heading">
            <h1>Twitch Streamers</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="heading slider">
            <div class="options all selected-tab">
                <div class="icon icon-all"></div>
                <span class="">All</span>
            </div>
            <div class="options active">
                <div class="icon icon-active"></div>
                <span class="hide">Online</span>
            </div>
            <div class="options offline">
                <div class="icon icon-offline"></div>
                <span class="hide">Offline</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**JS code**

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    $(".all, .active, .offline").on("click",selectOption);

    function selectOption(){
        $(".selected-tab span").addClass("hide");
        $(".selected-tab").removeClass("selected-tab");
        $(this).addClass("selected-tab");
        $(this).find("span").removeClass("hide");
        }
});
```

**CSS code**

```
                    #container{
            width: 80%;
            background-color: #B17878;
            margin: 0px auto;
        }
        .heading{
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .slider{
            width: 90px;    
            float: right;
            font-size: 14px;
            margin-top : 4px;
        }

        .options{
            width: 20px;
            height: 14px;
            float: right;
            padding: 2px;
            padding-right: 0px;
            clear: both;

            padding-left: 7px;
            margin-top: 4px;

            background-color: #eee;
            color: rgb(123, 97, 57);
            cursor: pointer;

            transition: width 0.5s linear;
            -webkit-transition : width 0.5s linear;

        }

        .icon{
            display: inline-block;
            width: 14px;
            height: 14px;
            border-radius: 50%;
        }

        .icon-all{
            background-color: rgb(123, 97, 57);
        }

        .icon-active{
            background-color: rgba(191,206,145,1);
        }

        .icon-offline{
            background-color: rgb(126, 144, 187);
        }

        .hide{
            display: none;
        }

        .selected-tab{
            width: 80px;
        }

        .options span{
            float: right;
            margin-right: 5px;
        }

        .options:hover{
            width: 80px;
        }
```

While i hover over ALL, online and offline multiple times like fast, the animation runs for the n number of times i triggered, i need some help to fix that, any suggestion would be AWESOME !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atlast found the issue and have fixed it, the solutions is,
I was mixing both css and jquery, which was unnecessay, on separtaing both, achieved the intended result

all i had to do was to add overflow

**CSS**

```
  .options{
            width: 20px;
            height: 14px;
            float: right;
            padding: 2px;
            padding-right: 0px;
            clear: both;

            padding-left: 7px;
            margin-top: 4px;

            overflow: hidden;

            background-color: #eee;
            color: rgb(123, 97, 57);
            cursor: pointer;

            transition: width 0.5s linear;
            -webkit-transition : width 0.5s linear;

        }
```

**JS**

```
$(".all, .active, .offline").on("click",selectOption);
            function selectOption(){
                $(".selected-tab").removeClass("selected-tab");
                $(this).addClass("selected-tab");
            }
```

And JS to keep track of the selected element. once the necessary changes where made the desired effect was achieved.

Answer (score 1):

From [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/hover/):

> The .hover() method binds handlers for both mouseenter and mouseleave
>   events. You can use it to simply apply behavior to an element during
>   the time the mouse is within the element.

so your .hover() was firing on both mouseenter and mouseleave. Change to this and it should work:

```
        $(".all, .active, .offline").mouseenter(expand);
        $(".all, .active, .offline").mouseleave(shrink);
```

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful, yet it didnt solve the real issue which i am facing, lets say if i hover all, online, offline, one at a time everything works great but when i hover over them like multiple times, and leave the animation repeats the no of times i hovered. I would like to understand how to control the animation. Like even if i repeatedly hover over them numerous times they should stop at the last mouseleave.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your main issue. Have you looked at the [jQuery .stop()](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) event? Will this do what you want?

Comment: Come to think of it, do you think if i separate the animation in jquery to transition in css(Just tried transition in css and works smooth than hover), and just click event to leave the element with 80px width, work ?

Comment: could you please take a look at the new updated code which i have edited, i think we are mostly through just need to figure out a way to delay the display of Text(all, online, offline) after the element has been expanded, right now it appears early and that too below the element.